Evaluating Dictionary Expressions (Fill in the Blank)
I feel like these shouldn't be nearly as difficult as the time I've spent on them...so I've finally come here 
What am I missing? Feel like I'm overthinking it.
enter image description here
enter image description here
for the len(blank) one specifically, I've tried subtracting one dict from the other in multiple ways, but nothing seemed to work.

There are lots of things that have a len() of zero - empty strings, empty lists, empty tuples, etc.  I guess that makes this a trick question, since the answer doesn't have anything to do with the given data.  (I am not impressed with these questions - #5 is simply broken, and the fact that your answer for #2 wasn't accepted indicates that they're lying to you about what expression is actually being evaluated.)

Yea idk what to do about #2...6 was len({})...that took me way too long lol.
Still not sure about 5 at all...
